# How can I get the unchanged Box form of an arbitrary expression?

Tags: front-end, boxes

One may observe that `MakeBoxes` does not give the actual Box form of various expressions:

```
MakeBoxes[{1*^4, 000123, a*b c}]
```

> ```
> RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{"10000", ",", "123", ",", RowBox[{"a", " ", "b", " ", "c"}]}], "}"}]
> ```

The `1*^4` was expanded, the leading zeros of `000123` were stripped, and the distinction between `*` and (space) was lost.

Also, `MakeBoxes` doesn't like syntactically invalid or incomplete strings:

```
MakeBoxes[0001+`1,*^6*a b]
```

> Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed.

How can one get the actual Box form visible with Show Expression (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>) without copy & paste?

Comment: In my answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28967/4330), in the section "Text file procedure" this problem is solved by extracting the boxes from the .nb file.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

My other answer is a nice solution for interactively looking at boxes, but in the comments, Mr.Wizard seems to be indicating that he's more interested in programmatic usage, and that he's definitely interested in seeing the box form after the FE has stripped non-semantic boxes to send to the kernel.  So here's a totally different method for doing this which achieves those goals.

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
 FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket["a*b c+d", True]]
```

The first argument to `UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket` must be a string, so this solution precludes 2D input unless you formulate the 2D input using linear syntax.  The second argument indicates whether the result should strip non-semantic boxes in the same way that the FE does at Shift+Enter time.  `True` indicates that it should strip (note the return value does not include the space between `b` and `c`).  Replacing it with `False` would leave the non-semantic boxes exactly as if they were being written to a notebook file.

If you're wondering what a non-semantic box is, this includes non-semantic spaces and several different box types if they have `StripOnInput` set to true.  The list, and default values of `StripOnInput` options can be found in the Option Inspector (just search for `StripOnInput`). `StyleBox` also takes the `StripOnInput` option.  By default, `StyleBox` is stripped in math but not in 2D or 3D graphics.  Here's an example of `StyleBox` stripping.

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
 FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[
  "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"x\",\"style\"]\)", True]]
```

returns just the `x` while

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
 FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[
  "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"x\",\"style\",StripOnInput->False]\)", True]]
```

returns the full `StyleBox`.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!

Comment: Welcome back around

Comment: This looks like the function I thought must exist.  The name is amazing.  Is there a reason  you don't use FrontEndExecute?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, `FrontEndExecute` is implemented in terms of ``MathLink`CallFrontEnd``, so the kernel definitions are functionally equivalent.  I have reasons for preferring ``MathLink`CallFrontEnd``, but they're quirky, and most people probably wouldn't find them relevant.  I can't take credit for the name...I think Jason Harris came up with it.

Answer (score 15):

Here's some code which produces an InputField and the box form of anything you type into the InputField as you type it:

```
DynamicModule[{boxes = ""}, 
 Column[{InputField[Dynamic[boxes], Boxes, ContinuousAction -> True], 
   Dynamic[boxes, BaseStyle -> {ShowStringCharacters -> True}]}]]
```

The critical idea here is using a `Boxes` style `InputField` to get the box form, which you can then work with programmatically.

I might have come up with this idea on my own, but I should give credit to Jason Harris who gave a typesetting workshop today and had an example very close to this, so this was on my mind.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you.  I notice that when I paste `{1*^4, 000123, a*b c}` it is *displayed* as `{1.\[Times]10^4, 000123, a*b c}` -- is there a way to keep `1*^4` as `1*^4` in the InputField itself?  Also, I notice that this preserves the spaces e.g. `"b", " ", "c"` while `$PreRead` does not; are you able to comment on that difference?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I noticed when I was preparing to post the answer that there seemed to be some oddness around your 1*^4 example as well.  I didn't investigate in great detail what's going on here, but I'm thinking there might be a minor bug here.  As far as spaces are concerned, there are a few canonicalizations the FE is allowed to make before sending boxes to the kernel. Stripping non-semantic spaces and non-semantic StyleBoxes are among those changes.  That the FE does this makes it much easier to write robust `MakeExpression` rules in the kernel.

Comment: That makes sense.  Is there any way to use `InputField` to get the version that is sent to the Kernel or $PreRead?

Comment: Ah...well, it turns out there's a completely different way to do this which additionally allows you to strip (or not) boxes, so long as you can formulate the input as a String.  That kind of sounds like what you want.  I'll edit the answer to reflect both solutions.

Comment: On second thought, I think I'll just add a whole new answer.  It really is a totally different approach.

Answer (score 5):

One approach that may be familiar to more experienced users is based on the input syntax described in [String Representation of Boxes](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/StringRepresentationOfBoxes.html).

> \(input\)                raw boxes

This appears to work but closer inspection shows that it is not exact:

```
"\({1*^4, 000123, a*b c}\)" // ToExpression
```

> ```
> RowBox[{"{",RowBox[{"1*^4",",","000123",",",RowBox[{"a","*","b","c"}]}],"}"}]
>
> RowBox[{"{",RowBox[{"1*^4",",","000123",",",RowBox[{"a","*","b"," ","c"}]}],"}"}]
> ```

(Copy & paste from Show Expression on the lower line.)
Greater changes are apparent in the invalid-expression example:

```
"\(0001+`1,*^6*a b\)" // ToExpression
```

> ```
> RowBox[{RowBox[{"0001","+",RowBox[{"`","1"}]}],",",RowBox[{"*",RowBox[{"^","6"}],"*","a","b"}]}]
>
> RowBox[{RowBox[{"0001","+","`1"}],",",RowBox[{"*",RowBox[{"^","6"}],"*","a"," ","b"}]}]
> ```

---

The other approach I know it to use `$PreRead` to capture the Box form input:

```
$PreRead = # /. {
     RowBox[{"raw", "[", raw__, "]"}] |
       RowBox[{raw__, "//", "raw"}] |
       RowBox[{"raw", "@", raw__}] :>
      ToString[Unevaluated[raw], StandardForm]
     } &;
```

Output still does not precisely match the Show Expression form but it is close:

```
raw[0001+`1,*^6*a b]
```

> ```
> RowBox[{RowBox[{"0001","+","`1"}],",",RowBox[{"*",RowBox[{"^","6"}],"*","a","b"}]}]
>
> RowBox[{RowBox[{"0001","+","`1"}],",",RowBox[{"*",RowBox[{"^","6"}],"*","a"," ","b"}]}]
> ```

The discrepancy actually ends up being advantageous as this is the form that is seen by `CellEvaluationFunction` and that was my original intent.

It is also more convenient than having to wrap input in `ToExpression["\( \)"]`.

I wonder if there is not a FrontEnd function that already does this.