# how can I generate a sequence of assignments?

Tags: variable-definitions, list-manipulation, meta-programming

I want to make a sequence like follows

```
r[1]=
r[2]=
r[3]=
r[4]=
....
r[n]=
```

The above `r[i]` represents coordinates which I have to type in manually one by one. So I make such a sequence to make the typing easier and more confortable. (even without having to type the `=`, I am so lazy, I admit). If the problem involve n coordinate, I just generate a sequence of length n.  So I naively write as follows

```
Table[r[i]= ,{i,1,n}]//TableForm
```

But with `=` there, I can't make such a list. So how could I generate a sequence of such incomplete expressions (like the above expressions, the `=` has no right side, this makes *Mathematica* can't table it)?

Comment: This is not a good way to write software.

Comment: @Nasser hey! your comment above should be kept in some distinguished place!

Comment: @Nasser Hi! Nasser. Thank you for your suggestion. But you leave a sentence without any further explanation. And I don't know why my way of typing input is not proper. The "r[i]" represents coordinate, when doing a specific calculation, I have to input initial coordinate manually one by one according to real situations. I can't find a better way to do it. Could you suggest a better way for me?

Comment: It sounds like you're building a data entry user interface. There might be a more natural way to do this, but it would help to describe more what you're doing.  E.g. is the size of the list, n, known ahead of time or can it vary?

Comment: @JoelKlein n is also dependant on specific question. But it won't vary within the same question. What I want to do is actually a plot on a zigzag line, and r[i] represent the turning point

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here and most probably Nasser's admonition rings true, but perhaps you want something like this?:

```
Do[
 CellPrint @
  Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{RowBox[{"r", "[", i, "]"}], "="}]], "Input"],
 {i, 5}
]
```

Alternatively you might make use of `\[Placeholder]` and `Defer`:

```
Do[CellPrint @ ExpressionCell[Defer[r[#] = \[Placeholder]], "Input"] & @ i, {i, 5}]
```

`Function` (short form `&`) is needed to get the value inside `Defer` as the latter has a Hold attribute.  See [Function in Table](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7756/121) for more.  `Array` as used below is more practical in this specific case, but I wanted to demonstrate using `Do` or `Table` as well in case your indexes are not the natural numbers.

Better still with all of these inputs in a single Cell:

```
Cell[
  BoxData[RowBox[
    Array[ToBoxes @ Defer[r[#] = \[Placeholder]] &, 5] ~Riffle~ "\n"
  ]],
  "Input"
] // CellPrint
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Now the advantage of using `\[Placeholder]` becomes clear: you can use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move between input fields.**

---

You may not want to use this kind of input method at all.  You can make assignments like this:

```
{r[1], r[2], r[3], r[4], r[5]} = {0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8}
```

You could get the left-hand side list with simply `Array[r, 5]` (assuming no prior assignments).

Depending on your application you could also store one list (array):

```
s = {0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8};
```

Then use `Part` to access elements:

```
{s[[2]], s[[5]]}
```

> ```
> {0.2, 0.8}
> ```

Perhaps you want each value on a separate line.  You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to create an ad hoc table:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

When evaluated the data looks like this:

> ```
> {{0.}, {0.2}, {0.4}, {0.6}, {0.8}}
> ```

You could use `Join` or `Flatten` to get back to the simple list form used with `s`.

You could also make assignments for a given list of values as [m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg) shows.

Comment: Yeah! That's exactly what I want. I have more questions. First, why there is `ToString` before i ? I found that it also works without `ToString`. Second, why there is two `RowBox`? I found that with only one `RowBox`, that is to write like **RowBox[{"r", "[", i, "]", "="}]**, will give result with a colored left bracket. Though the colored left brackets seems harmless, because I can set values normally. But I still curious about it. And finally both you and Nasser point it out that my way of input is not good. I leave a message for Nasser, would you take a look at it?

Comment: @user I was in a hurry last night.  You're right, `ToString` is unnecessary here.  Also, I got the Box structure quickly by typing `r[1]=` in a cell and using **Cell** > **Show Expression** (Ctrl+Shift+E on Windows), which is typically the simplest way to get the underlying Box form that *Mathematica* (or more specifically the FrontEnd) uses.  See [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13317/121) for another.  I'll add a couple of things to my answer that I hope you'll find useful or informative.

Comment: Hi,Wizard. Sorry for this late comment. Thank you very much for your elabrate and perfect answer. From you, I learned the cell structure.

Comment: @user15964 You're welcome, and thanks for the Accept.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing the OP is looking a way to generate a number of indexed assignments from a list of data elements. If so, then maybe something like the following will work for the OP:

```
Clear[data, r];
data = RandomInteger[{0, 99}, 5];
MapIndexed[(r[#2[[1]]] = #) &, data];

?r
```

> Global`r
>   r[1]=14
>   r[2]=95
>   r[3]=39
>   r[4]=26
>   r[5]=60

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplistic approach, I'd be interested in how it does or does not meet your requirements:

```
r={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

{r[[1]],r[[5]],r[[2]]}
```

> {1, 5, 2}

If you wanted a more structured input format, try setting the value of `r` equal to the result of the first part of an input table (via menus,  Insert->Table/Matrix->New ) which gives you something like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And then parts of `r` can be accessed as per the above example with `r[[n]]`.

Comment: damm I was just writing very same answer. Yes, the OP should just use a simple `list`

Comment: @Ajasja It certainly seems a possible solution. Sorry, I know that can be frustrating :(

Comment: @image_doctor Thank you, Image_doctor! I know what you mean, ,I actually want the input process more intuitive. I have edited my question to make myself clear.

Comment: @image_doctor No, no, I don't mean this as a serious comment (just forgot to end with a smiley:)