# Transform fancy usage messages in 1D string

Tags: string-manipulation, documentation, usage-messages

When we look at the usage messages of built-in functions nowadays (not in the good old times, when they were a simple descriptions) we see that although they look pretty in the front end, it is really hard to get a simple, one-dimensional string representation. Just try this and see yourself

```
ToString[Integrate::usage]
```

This is completely useless when one seeks for a simple string form. When you look at the *Wolfram Workbench* you may have noted, that they *do* provide simple string usage messages even for built-in functions.

**Question:** Is it possible to create/extract/steal simple, non-formatted usage messages for **all** (or almost all) built-in functions **automatically**? With *automatically* I mean having one function which works for almost all usage messages.

To give an example, the `Integrate` help message of the *Workbench* looks like this:

> Integrate[f,x] gives the indefinite integral Integral f dx. 
>   Integrate[f,{x,xmin,xmax}] gives the definite integral Integral  _xmin
>   ^xmax f dx.  Integrate[f,{x,xmin,xmax},{y,ymin,ymax},...] gives the
>   multiple integral Integral  _xmin ^xmaxdxIntegral  _ymin ^ymaxd y ...
>   f.
>
> Attributes: {Protected,ReadProtected} 
>   Options: {Assumptions,GenerateConditions,PrincipalValue}

Comment: Would it be possible to export it from the WB plugin?

Comment: I presume you've already tried playing with the second parameter of `ToString`?

Comment: @rm-rf I have tried to find some information in the plugin folder of Eclipse and indeed you find some stuff but not for built-in functions. Maybe I should carefully `grep` the contents of those folders again.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, but without luck. I'm open for ideas.

Comment: Sorry, no ideas. :-/

Comment: Infinite recursion: `TeXForm[Integrate::usage]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs I thought I don't mention this but it happens also when you try to use `ExportString` and "TeX" or "LaTeX". Trying to see how the LaTeX output looks was one way I tried too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I found an easy solution. Although my question was *how to extract a simple 1d string*, I show how to transform usages into nice and simple html. The rules for this can be adapted so that each box-structure is converted into whatever representation is wanted.

The basic trick is the following: A usage message consists of simple text and of special 2d string which are embraced in `"\!\(\*"` and `"\)"`. Now the way is to extract the contents of such a special string and to transform it into a *Mathematica* box expression. In this nested boxes we can replace reliable. This is the main difference to what @einbandi proposed who did this box replacement in the string which will always fail at some point.

Now we have to think about a set of rules to replace the box expressions. Since I wanted this for my IDEA plugin which can handle HTML, I will create a mixture of HTML and MathML. The boxes use pure HTML

```
boxRules = {
   StyleBox[f_, "TI"] :> {"<em>", f, "</em>"},
   StyleBox[f_, ___] :> {f},
   RowBox[l_] :> {l},
   SubscriptBox[a_, b_] :> {a, "<sub>", b, "</sub>"},
   SuperscriptBox[a_, b_] :> {a, "<sup>", b, "</sup>"},
   RadicalBox[x_, n_] :> {x, "<sup>1/", n, "</sup>"},
   FractionBox[a_, b_] :> {"(", a, ")/(", b, ")"},
   SqrtBox[a_] :> {"&radic;(", a, ")"},
   CheckboxBox[a_, ___] :> {"<u>", a, "</u>"},
   OverscriptBox[a_, b_] :> {"Overscript[", a, b, "]"},
   OpenerBox[a__] :> {"Opener[", a, "]"},
   RadioButtonBox[a__] :> {"RadioButton[", a, "]"},
   UnderscriptBox[a_, b_] :> {"Underscript[", a, b, "]"},
   UnderoverscriptBox[a_, b_, c_] :> {"Underoverscript[", a, b, c, 
     "]"},
   SubsuperscriptBox[a_, b_, c_] :> {a, "<sub><small>", b, 
     "</small></sub><sup><small>", c, "</small></sup>"}
   };
```

With this rules we can replace inside a box expression until nothing changes anymore.

```
convertBoxExpressionToHTML[boxexpr_] := 
 StringJoin[
  ToString /@ 
   Flatten[ReleaseHold[MakeExpression[boxexpr] //. boxRules]]]
```

This is basically everything you need to create a html-page of the usages of all known functions. Since I put some more stuff in it like

- creating of links to the official online documentation
- display of attributes
- display of options

I'll put the whole code at the end of this post and please note that it is not cleaned. The whole page looks then like this. Although there are some minor things (like nested 2d strings which are used about 5 times) I think for my plugin I can live with this:

[image]

```
extractUsage[str_] := 
 With[{usg = 
    Function[expr, expr::usage, HoldAll] @@ MakeExpression[str]},
  If[Head[usg] === String, usg, ""]]

createLinkName[s_] := 
 If[StringMatchQ[ToString@FullForm[s], "\"\\[" ~~ __ ~~ "]\""],
  {StringReplace[ToString@FullForm[s], {"\"" :> "", "\\" -> "\\\\"}],
   StringReplace[
    ToString@FullForm[s], {"\"" :> "", 
     "\\[" ~~ c__ ~~ "]" :> "character/" ~~ c}]},
  {s, s}]

createOptionString[s_] := 
 With[{opts = 
    Function[expr, Options[expr], HoldAll] @@ MakeExpression[s]},
  If[opts === {},
   "</p><b>Symbol has no options.</b>",
   "</p><b>Options: </b>" <> 
    StringJoin@Riffle[ToString[First[#]] & /@ opts, ", "]
   ]
  ]

createHtmlUsage[s_String] := Module[{
   usg = extractUsage[s],
   attr = Attributes[s],
   link, linkname},
  {linkname, link} = createLinkName[s];

  "<h3><a href=\"http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/" <> 
   link <> ".html\">" <> linkname <> "</a></h3>" <> If[usg =!= "",
    "<ul><li>" <>
     StringReplace[
      StringReplace[
       usg, {Shortest["\!\(\*" ~~ content__ ~~ "\)"] :> 
         convertBoxExpressionToHTML[content],
        "\n" :> "<li>"}
       ], {"\[Null]" :> "", 
       a_?(StringMatchQ[ToString@FullForm[#], 
            "\"\\[" ~~ __ ~~ "]\""] &) :> 
        StringReplace[
         ToString[a, MathMLForm], {WhitespaceCharacter :> ""}]}
      ] <> "</ul>", ""] <> "<b>Attributes:</b> " <> 
   StringJoin[ToString /@ Riffle[attr, ", "]] <> 
   createOptionString[s] <> "\n"
  ]

names = Names["System`*"];
Export["tmp/usageMessages.html", StringJoin[createHtmlUsage /@ names], "Text"]
```

Comment: But does IDEA render MathML ... ?

Comment: @Szabolcs Yep. When you press `Ctrl+q` (or `Ctrl+j` on Mac) and the documentation pops up then what you see are snips of HTML. I tried it and you can mix it with MathML. Looks awesome. I probably post a screenshot of that too.

Comment: Wow, that's a surprise!  I really wonder what rendering engine it uses.  I thought only Gecko had MathML support, and WebKit had a simple one which was turned on only in Safari (??)  Does it work on all platforms?

Comment: @Szabolcs Currently, I only tested it on OSX since I was writing it yesterday during a DVD. But the mix of html and MathML works in both, my Chrome and IDEA. I haven't really investigated in this issue, I just tried it because it was my only hope..

Comment: If I try [this page](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/mathml-samples/) and select MathML from the dropdown, Chrome doesn't render the MathML at all, Safari renders it poorly and Firefox renders it well.  But it's possible that the examples you have don't even use MathML because they only need subscripts?

Comment: @Szabolcs I used MathML only to replace all the `\[..]` characters like `\[Integral]`. For the sub/sup scripting I used html only since I wanted to keep it simple.

Answer (score 9):

**Edit:**

Since my old approach with `TeXForm` turned out to be quite a bad idea, here is a new one that uses `InputForm`. It is much more stable and already correctly covers many, many symbols. Let's start with the code:

```
usageString[s_Symbol] := Module[{string,
   rules = {
     "\\\"" ~~ a___ ~~ "\\\"" /; StringFreeQ[a, "\\"] :> a,
     "\"" ~~ a__ ~~ "\"" :> a,
     "StyleBox[" ~~ a___ ~~ ", " ~~ ("TI]" | "TR]") /; 
       StringFreeQ[a, "]"] :> a,
     "\\!\\(\\*" ~~ a___ ~~ "\\)" /; StringFreeQ[a, "\\("] :> a, 
     "SubscriptBox[" ~~ a__ ~~ ", " ~~ b__ ~~ "]" /; 
       StringFreeQ[a <> b, "Box" | "]"] :> a <> "_" <> b,
     "SuperscriptBox[" ~~ a__ ~~ ", " ~~ b__ ~~ "]" /; 
       StringFreeQ[a <> b, "Box" | "]"] :> a <> "^" <> b,
     "SubsuperscriptBox[" ~~ a___ ~~ ", " ~~ b___ ~~ ", " ~~ c___ ~~ 
        "]" /; StringFreeQ[a <> b <> c, "Box" | "]"] :> 
      a <> "_(" <> b <> ")^(" <> c <> ")"}
   },
  string = 
   Fold[StringReplace, ToString[MessageName[s, "usage"], InputForm], 
    rules];
  string = FixedPoint[StringReplace[#,
      "RowBox[{" ~~ a__ ~~ "}]" /; StringFreeQ[a, "RowBox" | "}]"] :> 
       a] &,
    string];
  StringReplace[StringJoin@StringSplit[string, ", "], "\\n" -> "\n"]
  ]
```

Before covering the main problem that `usageString` still has, let's have a look at what it *can* do (sorry, but I have to use images to convey this):

[image]

You can see that it transforms many of the `RowBox`, `SupersciptBox` etc. constructs found in those fancy usage messages to standard strings. It still lacks some tranformation rules, however, for things like `UnderoverscriptBox` or `StyleBox` with options:

[image]

I think that by adding some more replacement rules to cover the remaining boxing constructs and options, this could be a nice way to get simple string representations of the fancy 2D strings.

Comment: it does not work properly on mathematica 9 macos X. I get $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 4096 exceeded for usageString[Integrate::usage]

Comment: @chris This is not the fault of einbandi! Somehow `TeXForm` is broken. On Linux too. Just try `TeXForm[Integrate::usage]`.

Comment: @einbandi +1 for your effort, although I want to have it for all approx. 5000 symbols. If I have to look at the TeX-code for every message manually, it is maybe fast to just use `ToString` and rewrite incorrect text.

Comment: @halirutan Please have a look at the updated code. (Vll kann man damit ja mehr anfangen `:)`)

Answer (score 1):

i have a solution that uses the `UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket` as described by [John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/309/john-fultz)! in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13317/how-can-i-get-the-unchanged-box-form-of-an-arbitrary-expression) question.

This funny named Tool parses a String Input into the real unchanged Mathematica BoxForm.

This is my code:

```
str0 = Sum::usage

str1=StringJoin[ToString[StringReplace[#, "\\\"" -> "\""]]& /@
(Riffle[MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[str0, True]]〚1〛
//. RowBox[{seq___}] :> seq /. BoxData -> List, " "]
/. SubscriptBox[a_, b_] :> a<>"_"<>b
/. Except[List, _Symbol][args__] :> Sequence@@Riffle[{args}, " "])];

str2 = Fold[StringReplace, str1, 
{((WhitespaceCharacter...)~~br:("["|"("|"=") ~~ (WhitespaceCharacter ...)) :> br,
((WhitespaceCharacter ...) ~~ br:("]"|"}"|","|".")) :> br, 
(br:("{") ~~ (WhitespaceCharacter ...)) :> br, 
". " ~~ Except[EndOfString] -> ". \n"}]
```

and this is how the Output looks like (first Output formatted fancy `str0`, second simple flat `str2`)

[image: first Output formatted fancy str0, second simple flat str2]

**Code Explanation:**

*str0* is the formatted string with all the StyleBoxes and other formatting boxes.

*str1*:

`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[str0, True]` gives Boxes and strips off all `StyleBoxes`, thats because the second argument is True.
First Replacement removes all `RowBoxes`. The outer `BoxForm` changed to a List of strings. Whitespaces are inserted between these strings the by `Riffle`. SubscriptBox gets a special treatment. The last line replaces every remaining FormatBox such as `UnderoverscriptBox` and it does that by adding Whitespaces between the arguments, and returning the arguments as a flat Sequence.

**Edit:**

```
ToString[StringReplace[#, "\\\"" -> "\""]]& /@
```

was added to include more cases such as `StringReplace::usage` like [halirutan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/187/halirutan) mentioned in his comment. This cases include string representations `""` 
with Styles inside of a the usage-string, when `"args"` has to be given as strings. Its funny that `StringReplace` helped to fix its own usage-Message :))

*str2*:

In this block of code i only remove unwanted `WhitespaceCharacter` from the string str1 and i add linebreaks `"/n"` after the `"."`, because they got lost during the Parsing. There are 3 different cases where `WhitespaceCharacter` can be removed.
1 removing left-and right sided `WithespaceCharacter` from a character like `"["`. 
2. and 3. removing WithespaceCharacter from left(2) or right(3) side.

**Context of this Answer**

I found this question important because i am currently working on rewriting the [ApplicationMaker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574710/integrating-notebooks-to-mathematicas-documentation-center) by [jmlopez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/788553/jmlopez) for automatic creation of Mathematica Documentation. If you want to build ReferencePages, you might use the usage information to fill in some contents. The formatted usage-messages can be used to make a definitionbox of the symbol, but for the summary that appears, when you search for a symbol you need a simple flat String, otherwise all the StyleBoxes will show up. This is also discussed here: [formatting usage messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570770/formatting-usage-messages)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you got my upvote. Not to discourage you, but only to show that there are a lot of places that call for trouble, try: `str0 = StringReplace::usage`. For my usage-extractor I had to make sure that really all usages work.

Comment: @halirutan Thanks for your comment. I added another line to include these cases. Can you find another exception, where my code goes wrong?
You may know some "hard" formatted usage-messages, i only tested a few.

Comment: Some of them are not only hard cases, they are plain wrong. I don't remember which exactly, but most of the times it happened with usage strings that itself contained strings with formatting like the `StringReplace` example I gave. Since I had to convert *all* of them, I just stopped when errors happened and looked what went wrong.

Comment: Btw, if you write a function that takes a symbol (or the symbol name as string) and returns the formatted usages, be very careful to never evaluate the symbol on its way through your function. Nowadays, we have simple *variables* that want to connect you to the internet. Try for instance `f[s_] := MessageName[s, "usage"]; f[$CloudRootDirectory]`

Comment: good hint but `MessageName[s,"usage"]` is equivalent to `s::usage`.
s::usage also holds its argument s, since MessageName has Attribute HoldFirst. But something like `Evaluate[Symbol["SymbolName"]]::usage` would be dangerous. I have no clue how to prevent a Symbol from Evaluation, when i have to transform from the symbolName(String) to the Symbol, because this Transformation allready is somehow an Evaluation... maybe with `ToExpression["SymbolName", StandardForm, Hold]`?

Comment: It was just an example to show what I mean. You can use for instance constructs like the following to prevent evaluation until the symbol reaches `MessageName`. Look here: `Function[s, MessageName[s, "usage"], {HoldFirst}] @@ 
 MakeExpression["$CloudRootDirectory"]`

Comment: Thanks but your code does not work... i ask a new question for this and link it here

Comment: It should work and it does for me: `Import["http://goo.gl/NaH6rM"]["http://i.stack.imgur.com/6dIjY.png"]`

Comment: Your solution is indeed very clever! There was just a second argument missing in MakeExpression and I just did not understand the syntax, because i only used @@ for lists before. I think `MessageName[#, "usage"] & @@ 
 MakeExpression["$CloudRootDirectory", StandardForm]`will also work because MessageName allready has Attribut HoldFirst. Thank you again.

Comment: No, unfortunately it won't work. I could explain it, but this should probably happen in the [Chat].

Answer (score 1):

In order to obtain the non-formatted usage string for any symbol, e.g. `Integrate`, you can just use `WolframLanguageData["Integrate", "PlaintextUsage"]`.

A function which does this for any symbol may be defined as

```
plainUsage[sym_] := WolframLanguageData[ToString[sym], "PlaintextUsage"]
```

For example:

[image: plainUsage[Solve] result]

Of course, the string may still contain a few special characters, such as the integral sign which you can convert to `\[Integral]` using `FullForm`.