# How to get Information as a string?

Tags: information-function

I'd like to get the usage statement returned by `Information[]` as a plaintext string - not boxes, is there a function for this?

This is silly:

```
Information@ImageCrop
c = NotebookRead@PreviousCell[];
ToString[ToExpression@c[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: `ImageCrop::usage // ToString`?

Comment: Ah that is too easy

Comment: You may be interested in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22779/5478

Comment: Expanding on @Kuba comment: `info[sym_Symbol] := ToString[sym] <> "::usage // ToString"  // ToExpression`

Comment: I don't very sure.Maybe you mean `WolframLanguageData["ImageCrop", "TypesetUsage"]`

Comment: @yode I think that should be `WolframLanguageData["ImageCrop", "PlaintextUsage"]`.

Comment: @Edmund Ok.I missed that. :)