# How to get the parameter number of inbuilt function

Tags: functions, function-construction

I want to make a custom function `parameterNumber`,which can return the parameter number of inbuilt function,as the `Plot`'s documentation:
[image]

So the result of `parameterNumber[Plot]` is `{{2}}`

Or the `RelationGraph`'s documentation:
[image]
So the result of `parameterNumber[RelationGraph]` is `{{2},{3}}`

Or the `Plus`,`Plus[arg1_,arg2_,arg3_,...]` is valid,So the result of `parameterNumber[Plus]` is `{0,Infinity}`
How to make a such function?

---

#### Status of current answer

The current method have little flaw still,Such as the MB1965's answer:

```
{#, paramNum[#]} & /@ {Plot, paramNum, Integrate, MemberQ, 
   Plot3D} // Column
```

[image]

Or the Mr.Wizard's answer:

```
{#,info[#]}&/@{Plot,Integrate,MemberQ,Plot3D}//Column
```

[image]

---

Related [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7040/21532),but not very similar.And I think the `` Developer`CheckArgumentCount ``,`Check`,`` Internal`ProcessEquations`GetArguments `` or the `ArgumentCountQ` maybe can help this.

Comment: `?Plot` produces a number of relevant pieces of information about `Plot[]`. One such piece of information is the different 'ways' you can call `Plot[]`. Perhaps you should look for a way to access the cells that are output from `?fun` or `??func` and then operate on their contents. Note that the formal number of different options for a function such as `Plot[]` is provided by `Options[func]` and in _Plot_'s case there are 62 different options available.

Comment: Maybe you mean `WolframLanguageData["Plot", 
 EntityProperty["WolframLanguageSymbol", "PlaintextUsage"]]`,so I post [another post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125391/how-to-get-the-longest-bracket-pair)

Comment: Have you seen `SyntaxInformation[]`?

Comment: @J.M. Yes,I have,but I fail to understant that string option that time,such as `LocalVariables`.

Comment: @yode Can you specify exactly what, in your opinion, is insufficient or needs improvement in the existing answers? It would help to focus the question.

Comment: @MarcoB I have uptated the status for current answer.

Answer (score 6):

Since you start from the perspective of documentation perhaps using the Symbol's usage message would be appropriate.  I'll start with einbandi's `usageString` from [Transform fancy usage messages in 1D string](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22779/121).

```
info[s_Symbol] :=
  With[
    {examples =
      StringCases[usageString[s], ToString[s] ~~ "[" ~~ Except["]"] ... ~~ "]"]},
    Length /@ Unevaluated @@@ ToHeldExpression @ examples // Union
  ]
```

I am sure it's *not* perfect but it may be a useful place to start.  Intelligently combine this with J. M.'s implicit suggestion to use [`SyntaxInformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxInformation.html) and you may have a fairly robust method.

Comment: Wow,thanks a lot.As [this case](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-12-17-07-45-08.png), the `info` should give `{0,1,2}`.Actually I have considered that `SyntaxInformation`,I will try it again when I get an laptop.

Comment: @yode I made two small changes to conform to that example.

Comment: Wow,you made it...But sometimes little bug?Such as we cannot run `info[Plot]`?And I realize the answer should end with `SyntaxInformation` eventually maybe?

Comment: If we cannot get a perfect solution,I will give the bounty to your this answer. :)

Comment: @yode Like I said this is not perfect but hopefully it is still useful in some way.  On my system (v10.1 under Windows) the updated code above returns `{2}` for `info[Plot]`.  What are you experiencing?

Comment: Really?The `{2}` is my expected indeed,but I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj3fv.png).

Comment: @yode I am guessing that the generic format of the usage messages has been changed in v11 and einbandi's pattern matching is no longer sufficient.  This is the danger of trying to extract information in that way.  I shall try to think of a more robust approach.

Comment: @yode It seems that `WolframLanguageData` was added sometime after version 10.1.0 so I am afraid I cannot help there.

Comment: The bounties will expired soon.Thanks to your endeavor for this topic though it cannot be solved still. :)

Comment: @yode Wow, I was not expecting a bounty on this answer.  I feel a little guilty for not being more helpful. :-/

Comment: Oh,don't be that feeling.You help me all the time,which do deserve more. :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a (rather hacky but robust-ish) way to reduce patterns down to the number of arguments they occupy:

```
reduceSpans[spans_] :=
 # /. Except[_Symbol | _Span | _Integer | ∞] -> 1 & /@ spans //.
  {
   (m_ ;; n_ ;; l_) :> (m + n) ;; l,
   (Hold | List)[a___, PatternSequence[m_Integer, n_Integer], 
     b___] :> {a, m + n, b},
   (Hold | List)[a___, PatternSequence[m_Integer, n_ ;; k_], 
     b___] :> {a, (m + n) ;; k, b},
   (Hold | List)[a___, PatternSequence[m_ ;; k_, n_Integer], 
     b___] :> {a, m ;; (k + n), b},
   (Hold | List)[a___, PatternSequence[m_ ;; k_, n_ ;; j_], 
     b___] :> {a, (m + n) ;; (k + j), b}
   }
reducePatterns[p_, opsRep_: (0 ;; ∞)] :=
  p /. {
      _Symbol?(Function[s, 
          MatchQ[Unevaluated[s], 
           Except[Pattern | Optional | Blank | BlankSequence | 
             BlankNullSequence | PatternSequence | OptionsPattern]
           ], HoldFirst]) -> List
      } //. {
     Verbatim[Blank][___] -> 1,
     Verbatim[BlankSequence][___] -> (1 ;; ∞),
     Verbatim[BlankNullSequence][___] -> (0 ;; ∞),
     _OptionsPattern :> opsRep,
     Verbatim[HoldPattern][
        Verbatim[Pattern][a_, b_]
        ] | Verbatim[Pattern][a_, b_] :> b,
     Verbatim[PatternTest][a_, b_] :> a,
     Verbatim[Optional][a_, b_] :> (0 ;; a),
     Verbatim[Optional][a_] :> (0 ;; 1)
     } // reduceSpans;
```

This basically reduces the pattern down to simple pattern elements then adds the component numbers for those.

Then we can apply this to `SyntaxInfo` (with a little bit of hacking):

```
paramsBySInfo[sinfo_List, opsLen_: 0] :=

  With[{loc = Replace["LocalVariables" /. sinfo, _String -> {}], 
    arp = "ArgumentsPattern" /. sinfo},
   ParameterSequence @@
    Fold[
     Replace[#2,
       {
        {i_Integer, ___} :>
         If[
          Length@# < i,
          Replace[#, {
            {Span[n_, m_], r___} :>
             {Span[Max@{i, n}, Max@{i, m}], r}
            }],
          #
          ],
        _ :> #
        }] &,
     reducePatterns[arp, opsLen],
     loc
     ]
   ];
```

And for good measure apply it to `DownValues` too:

```
paramsByDVs[dvs_List, opsLen_: 0] :=

  With[{choices = 
     Replace[First@#, Verbatim[HoldPattern][_[a___]] :> Hold[a]] & /@ 
      dvs},
   ParameterSequence @@@ (reducePatterns[#, opsLen] &) /@ choices
   ];
```

Then write a wrapper that tries `SyntaxInformation` first, then `DownValues`:

```
paramNum[f_Symbol] :=
  Replace[
   SyntaxInformation@f, {
    {} :>
     Replace[
      DownValues[f], {
       {} -> 0,
       e_ :> paramsByDVs[e, Length@Options@f]
       }
      ],
    e_ :> paramsBySInfo[e, Length@Options@f]
    }
   ];
```

This gives pretty close to what you want I think:

```
In[375]:= paramNum /@ {Plot, paramNum, Integrate, MemberQ, Plot3D}

Out[375]= {
 ParameterSequence[2 ;; ∞], 
 {ParameterSequence[1]}, 
 ParameterSequence[2 ;; ∞], 
 ParameterSequence[1 ;; 3], 
 ParameterSequence[2 ;; ∞]
 }
```

Note that I supplied the number of options to my reduction functions, as that's the max number `OptionsPattern[]` should be able to take.

Comment: Thanks very very much,and we can just consider built-in function.,but there are some accidents in [this code](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-12-20-08-11-35.png)? :)

Comment: Ah yeah, I didn't escape there no being a LocalVariables spec. I'll do that when I have Mathematica open again. First one I'll need to look at.

Comment: @yode I cleaned those pieces, fixed up some stuff in adjusting for local variables, and added the max number of options for `OptionsPattern[]`. Hopefully this suits your needs better.

Comment: But the `paramNum[Plot]` give `ParameterSequence[2 ;; \[Infinity]]`?

Comment: That's because `SynatxInformation@Plot` gives `{"ArgumentsPattern"->{___,OptionsPattern[]},"LocalVariables"->{Plot,{2}}}`. The infinity comes from that first argument and the 2 comes from the `"LocalVariables"` spec. I figured where there are local variables you can assume there are at least that many arguments, but not necessarily that there will be no more arguments (excluding `OptionsPatterns`). If you are willing to make that assumption, when a `"LocalVariables"` spec is provided, all the information can come from that and the number of `Options`.

Comment: I have realize this target meet many many cases it should,if you use `SynatxInformation`.

Comment: Do you mean using just the `"LocalVariables"` spec or the general pattern reduction idea? I think for most standard cases, yes, just using `"LocalVariables"` will work, but it may miss more exotic cases and I didn't want to miss those.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50399/discussion-between-yode-and-mb1965).

Answer (score 4):

an idea to work with:

```
len = 0;
Quiet[While[
   Check[Plot[Evaluate[Sequence @@ ConstantArray[0, {len}]]], 0,
     {Plot::argr, Plot::argrx}] == 0, ++len]];
len
```

> 2

I do not see how to readily generalize however

Comment: Thanks a lot!Maybe `WolframLanguageData["RelationGraph", 
 EntityProperty["WolframLanguageSymbol", 
  "DocumentationExampleInputs"]]` or `WolframLanguageData["Plot", EntityProperty["WolframLanguageSymbol", "PlaintextUsage"]]` can help a little.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different approach that uses an information file that comes with Mathematica. For the moment, I will not turn the results into what you suggested. Instead, I will return the complete call pattern for all `` System` `` built-in functions. The number of arguments can be extracted from this call pattern if required.

```
functionInformation = 
  With[{file = 
     First[FileNames[
       "FunctionInformation.m", {$InstallationDirectory}, Infinity]]},
    Rule @@@ Get[file]];
info = Association @@ 
   Rule @@@ ("System`" /. functionInformation)[[All, {1, 2}]];
```

Now, you can use this `Association` to get the call pattern for all system functions:

```
info/@{"Plot","Integrate","MemberQ","Plot3D"}//Column

(*
{___,OptionsPattern[]}
{_,_,Optional[{__}],___,OptionsPattern[]}
{_,_.,_.,OptionsPattern[]}
{___,OptionsPattern[]}
*)
```

### Edit

To create an output like in the question, one has to inspect each argument for a call pattern and create a `{min,max}` pair. For instance `__` will create `{1,Infinity}`, while a single `Blank` gives `{1,1}`.

To make this consistent, we need to handle all possible patterns from this list:

```
Flatten[Values[info], 1] // DeleteDuplicates
```

Most cases can be handled together so that the final `argLen` function has only some definitions:

```
argLen[Verbatim[_] | Verbatim[Pattern][_, Verbatim[_]]] := {1, 1};
argLen[Verbatim[__] | Verbatim[Pattern][_, Verbatim[__]]] := {1, Infinity};
argLen[Verbatim[___] | Verbatim[Pattern][_, Verbatim[___]]] := {0, Infinity};
argLen[Verbatim[Optional][_]] := {0, 1};
argLen[Verbatim[OptionsPattern][]] := {0, Infinity};
argLen[_Symbol | _List | _String] := {1, 1};
```

The final `paraNum` function combines the min/max values for all arguments from a call pattern

```
paraNum[f_String] := ParameterSequence[
  Span @@ (Plus @@@ Transpose[argLen /@ info[f]])]
```

For your examples you get

```
{#,paraNum[#]}&/@{"Plot","Integrate","MemberQ","Plot3D"}//Column

(*
{Plot,ParameterSequence[0;;∞]}
{Integrate,ParameterSequence[2;;∞]}
{MemberQ,ParameterSequence[1;;∞]}
{Plot3D,ParameterSequence[0;;∞]} 
*)
```

Please note that `MemberQ` has an option, so your own answer is not correct. The call pattern for `Plot3D` is not given in detail and only says `{___, OptionsPattern[]}` which is wrong when you want to use it in this approach.

Comment: I find very hard to convert it into that suggestion result due to the existence of `"LocalVariables"`.I give a try in [following](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138615/21532).If you have a better method.Let me know please.

Answer (score 1):

Almost,but not a perfect method.And since based on `SyntaxInformation`,which cannot adapt `{DirectedEdges, EquirippleFilterKernel, NetTrain, ProcessEstimator,URLSaveAsynchronous}`.So I give a specify value for it,respectively.

```
SetAttributes[paramNum, HoldFirst]
paramNum[NetTrain] := {{2}, {3}}
paramNum[URLSaveAsynchronous] := {{3}}
paramNum[EquirippleFilterKernel] := {{2}}
paramNum[fun_Symbol] := 
 Module[{pattern = SyntaxInformation[fun], loc, bankPattern, need, 
   option, range}, 
  If[StringContainsQ[ToString[Unevaluated[fun]], "$"], 
   "System variables", 
   If[SyntaxInformation[fun] === {} || 
     MemberQ[{ProcessEstimator, DirectedEdges}, fun], 
    "Option or Autoevaluating symbol", 
    bankPattern = 
     SequenceCases[
      "ArgumentsPattern" /. 
       SyntaxInformation[fun], {a___, ___OptionsPattern} :> a]; 
    need = Count[bankPattern, Verbatim[_] | _List]; 
    option = Count[bankPattern, Verbatim[_.] | _Optional]; 
    If[KeyMemberQ[pattern, "LocalVariables"] && 
      ListQ["LocalVariables" /. pattern], 
     loc = Max[Last["LocalVariables" /. pattern]]; 
     If[MemberQ[bankPattern, Verbatim[__]], 
      range = MinMax[{need + 1, Min[{Infinity, loc}], need + option}];
       If[AllTrue[range, NumericQ], List /@ Range @@ range, range], 
      If[MemberQ[bankPattern, Verbatim[___]], 
       range = MinMax[{need, Min[{Infinity, loc}], need + option}]; 
       If[AllTrue[range, NumericQ], List /@ Range @@ range, range], 
       If[AllTrue[MinMax[{need, loc, need + option}], NumericQ], 
        List /@ Range @@ MinMax[{need, loc, need + option}], 
        MinMax[{need, loc, need + option}]]]], 
     If[MemberQ[bankPattern, Verbatim[__]], {need + 1, Infinity}, 
      If[MemberQ[bankPattern, Verbatim[___]], {need, Infinity}, 
       List /@ Range[need, need + option]]]]]]]
```

#### Examples

```
Grid[{#, SyntaxInformation[#], paramNum[#]} & /@ 
  ToExpression[
   CanonicalName[RandomEntity["WolframLanguageSymbol", 10]]], 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]

But I have to say the `SyntaxInformation` will give wrong information except `{DirectedEdges, EquirippleFilterKernel, NetTrain,ProcessEstimator,URLSaveAsynchronous}`,which will result to a unexpected answer.Such as:
[image] 
Actually,the output of `Plot` should be `{{2}}`,the output of `FindCycle` and `FindClique` should be `{{1}, {2}, {3}}`.

So I look forward a better solution.