# built-in functions with one argument

Tags: list-manipulation, built-in-symbols

I want to find the (`NumericFunction`) built-in functions that take exactly one document.

```
Select[Names["*"], MemberQ[Attributes[#], NumericFunction] &]
```

returns a list of numeric functions but among them there are both functions like 
`Sin`and `QHypergeometricPFQ`.

How can I be more specific? Thanks.

Comment: You can try to use it:   

`Select[Select[Names["*"], MemberQ[Attributes[#], NumericFunction] &], 
 MatchQ[SyntaxInformation[Symbol[#]], {_ -> {_}}] &]`

Comment: @KirillBelov I have to say the `SyntaxInformation` don't very fit such case.How about those function with two argument?

Comment: @Dimitris wanted to get built-in functions with one argument. In other cases you can apply another pattern `MatchQ[SyntaxInformation[func], pattern]`

Comment: @KirillBelov Look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138615/21532)