# How to print unevaluated arguments in the form they were originally typed in?

Tags: evaluation, output-formatting

I'm looking for a way to print a function's arguments, not only unevaluated, but also in the way they were originally typed in.

By way of experimentation, I tried stuff like this:

```
echo[x___] := ToString[Unevaluated[x]];
SetAttributes[echo, HoldAll];
```

...but nothing quite worked.  For example, with the above function, the expression

```
Print[TemplateApply[">``<", echo[2^2, "foo", 2 + 2, None]]]
```

outputs this to the screen:

```
>          2
Sequence[2 , foo, 2 + 2, None]<
```

Instead, I want the output to be this:

```
>2^2, "foo", 2 + 2, None<
```

IOW, I want the output of `echo` to be a string that more closely represents the arguments as they were typed in to *Mathematica*<sup>1</sup>.

How can I achieve this?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> The amount of whitespace between the arguments, however, is not too important.  E.g., either `1  ,2,3` or
`1, 2, 3` would be OK as the value of `echo[1  ,2,3]`.  Similarly, preserving fancy typesetting is of secondary importance.  The example above shows some of the deviations from perfect faithfulness that I'm most trying to avoid: the `Sequence[...]` wrapper, the added second line to accommodate the superscript, and the omission of the double-quotes around strings.</sub>

Comment: What if someone enters the `2^2` as real superscript? I guess it should be printed then as real superscript and this is the point where it becomes hard to achieve what you like. Anyway, first you can try `ToString[Unevaluated[x], InputForm]` but it will turn every fancy typesetting into usual code.

Comment: @halirutan: thanks for the tip.  It's an improvement, although it does not get rid of the `Sequence[ ... ]` wrapper.  BTW, getting 2^2 instead of 2<sup>2</sup> is acceptable.  I'll edit my question to clarify this point.

Comment: Related question on Stack Overflow: [(12598697)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12598697/618728)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know I have answered a very similar question before but I can't find it now.  Of what I can find my own question [How can I get the unchanged Box form of an arbitrary expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13317/121) is probably closest, though more recently [Why aren't parentheses ( ) an expression in Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82873/121) maybe closer in application to what you need.  For pursuing your goal it is important to understand how *Mathematica* input works.  Please refer to the **Sidebar: Box form manipulation** section of my answer in the second linked Q&A for a foundation.

Since the Box form is lost by the time your `echo` function is evaluated you cannot achieve complete transcription by normal means.  However you can use a Box-level preprocessing to handle things in a nonstandard way.

```
p0 = RowBox[{arg___}] | arg_;

$PreRead = # /. 
    RowBox[{"echo", "[", p0, "]"}] |
    RowBox[{"echo", "@", p0}] | 
    RowBox[{p0, "//", "echo"}] :> 
       RowBox[{"echo", "[",
           With[{x = Unique[]}, x = {arg}; ToString@Unevaluated@x],
       "]"}] &;
```

With this definition in place Front End uses of `echo` now spit out their raw Box content wrapped in a `List`:

```
echo[1*^99, 2^2]
```

> ```
> echo[{"1*^99", ",", RowBox[{"2", "^", "2"}]}]
> ```

Note that no amount of `HoldComplete` type measures will preserve the same.  From here you could process the Box data as necessary but beware that it can get hairy quickly.

Your revised requirements seem less stringent than this after all so a less severe approach may be in order.  Perhaps you simply want to avoid the multi-line formatting of [`OutputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OutputForm.html) and the appearance of "Sequence" in the result and this may do:

```
$PreRead = .   (* clear earlier definition *)

echo[args___] := ToString[Unevaluated @ {args}, InputForm] ~StringTake~ {2, -2}

Print[TemplateApply[">``<", echo[2^2, "foo", 2 + 2, None]]]
```

> ```
> >2^2, "foo", 2 + 2, None<
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Let me through a first version into the room:

```
SetAttributes[echo, HoldAll];
echo[x___] := StringRiffle[{##}, ", "] & @@ 
   Function[arg, ToString[Unevaluated[arg], InputForm], {HoldFirst}] /@
   Hold[x];
```

Now you get

```
Print[TemplateApply[">``<", echo[2^2, "foo", 2 + 2, None]]]

(* >2^2, "foo", 2 + 2, None< *)
```

**Be aware** that you might need `HoldAllComplete` and `HoldComplete` if you want

```
echo[Sequence[1, 2, 3]]
```

really return `Sequence[1,2,3]` as one argument. The same is true for `Unevaluated` arguments.

Comment: > `StringRiffle` - new in 10.1?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Uhh, yes. Didn't notice that. I guess just don't even look up function names anymore. I just write what I think should exist as a function :-)

Comment: The win of *Mathematica* is that this approach works :-D