# Remove subscript from string

Tags: export, string-manipulation, subscript

I have a list that I am using for the legend of a plot

```
gases = {"Air", "He", "Ar", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(2\)]\)", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(CO\), \(2\)]\)"};
```

However, I also want to `Export` the data as a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) table. When I do this the header gets all wacky:

```
ExportString[Join[{gases}, RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {2, 5}]], "CSV"]
```

> ```
> "Air,He,Ar,\"N \"
>   2,\"CO \"
>    2
> 0,0,0,1,1
> 1,1,0,1,1"
> ```

This is obviously because of the `SubscriptBox`. So how can I remove these so that

```
Foo[gases]
    {"Air", "He", "Ar", "N2", "CO2"}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A slightly more general version of JasonB's solution:

```
deSubscript[string_] := StringReplace[string,
  "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(" ~~ Shortest[x__] ~~ "\), \(" ~~ 
    Shortest[y__] ~~ "\)]\)" :> x <> y
  ];
```

which also works if the string contains something other than a single `SubscriptBox`:

```
In[243]:= subscriptBoxToString["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(aH\), \(2\)]\)\!\
\(\*SubscriptBox[\(123\), \(3\)]\)"]
subscriptBoxToString["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(C\), \(2\)]\) \
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(NH\), \(3\)]\)"]
subscriptBoxToString["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(CO\), \(2\)]\)"]

Out[243]= "aH21233"

Out[244]= "C2 NH3"

Out[245]= "CO2"
```

Answer (score 8):

This would need to be modified for other forms, but it does what you are asking

```
deSubscript = 
  StringReplace[#, 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(" ~~ var__ ~~ "\), \(" ~~ sub_ ~~ "\)]\)" :>
      var <> sub] &;
gases = {"Air", "He", "Ar", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(2\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(CO\), \(2\)]\)"};
deSubscript[gases]
(* {"Air", "He", "Ar", "N2", "CO2"} *)
```

Comment: Sorry, went with the more general one that glS posted

Comment: No apology needed

Answer (score 7):

The most straightforward approach is to convert your string representation of boxes into explicit boxes, and then apply a replacement rule. The internal function which does this was uncovered by [John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13371/280):

```
stringToBoxes[s_String] := 
 MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[s, False]][[1, 1]]
```

Now

```
stringToBoxes /@ gases /. SubscriptBox[x_, y_] :> x <> y
```

> ```
> {"Air", "He", "Ar", "N2", "CO2"}
> ```

Note that this approach won't lead to evaluation leaks if symbols with names `Air`, `He` etc. have values because these names are kept as strings during the conversion.

The above solution can be easily generalized for handling more complicated 2D labels, for example:

```
label = "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \({1,2,3}\)]\)"
```

> [image: output]

```
Replace[stringToBoxes@label, 
 box : _RowBox | _SubscriptBox | _SuperscriptBox :> StringJoin @@ box, {0, Infinity}]
```

> ```
> "N{1,2,3}"
> ```

Answer (score 6):

A string replacement method using the two lines obtained from `ToString` with mainly `StringPosition` and `StringReplacePart`.

```
ClearAll[toStringWithSubscript];
toStringWithSubscript[str_String] :=
 Module[{lines = StringSplit[ToString[str], "\n"], subPos},
  subPos = 
   StringPosition[Last@lines, Longest[Except[WhitespaceCharacter] ..],
     Overlaps -> False];
  StringReplacePart[
   StringJoin[First@lines, StringRepeat[" ", First@Differences[StringLength /@ lines]]],
   StringTake[Last@lines, subPos],
   subPos]
  ]
```

`ToString` on a string with subscripts gives you two lines the second of which contains the substrings. Both lines are padded such that if you used a fixed width font the subscripts would line up under the first line.

Using this information the positions of the subscripts can be collected from the second line using `StringPosition` and inserted with replacement into the first line using `StringReplacePart`.  We have to pad the end of the first line if the string ended in a subscript as `ToString` does not pad on the ends.

[image]

With a little work this can be extended to consider superscripts and jointly subscripts and superscripts as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

```
ToString /@ ((Row[{##}] & @@ ToExpression[#, InputForm]) & /@ gases)
```

> ```
>  {"Air", "He", "Ar", "N2", "CO2"}
> ```

Not safe if `Air`, `CO` and other symbols have global values.

And here is a more flexible method, which should not leak evaluation like the former:

```
 CO=4;He=5;
 Internal`InheritedBlock[{Format,  Subscript, Row}
    ,
    SetAttributes[{Subscript, Row}, HoldAll];
    Format[Subscript[x_, y_]] := Row[{x, y}];

    ToExpression[
       #, StandardForm, Function[s, ToString[Unevaluated@s], HoldFirst]
    ] & /@ gases
 ]
```

> ```
>  {"Air", "He", "Ar", "N2", "CO2"}
> ```