# Convert String to clean file-name

Tags: export, string-manipulation

When I extract `PlotLabel` from my `List` of plots using

```
PlotLabel /. AbsoluteOptions[plotList[[1]], PlotLabel]
```

I get strings like

```
"M vs. \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(n\), \(sync\)]\) - Dutycycle: 20%"
  (* or *)
"M vs. Subscript[n, sync] - Dutycycle: 20%"
```

[image: rendered string]

Now I want to export this list of plots in such a way, that the file-name is related to the `PlotLabel` that I extracted before.

How can I make this string suitable for a filename, including:

- replace white-space with `"_"`
- make subscript just normal: `Subscript[n, sync]` --> `nsync`
- remove characters that cannot be in file-names, like `":"` or `"%"`

?

A result could look like

```
"M_vs_nsync_-_Dutycycle_20"
```

Comment: `StringReplace` may be useful http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace.html

Comment: Related: [(29817)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29817/121), [(126495)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126495/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:**

With the more messy form of the string:

```
str = "M vs. \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(n\), \(sync\)]\) - Dutycycle: 20%"
```

one can use the function [`deSubscript` by glS](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/126499/22013) (thanks to [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130771/convert-string-to-clean-file-name#comment353026_130771)):

```
deSubscript[string_] := StringReplace[string,
  "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(" ~~ Shortest[x__] ~~ "\), \(" ~~ 
    Shortest[y__] ~~ "\)]\)" :> x <> y
  ]
```

to get

```
str1 = deSubscript[str]
```

> `"M vs. nsync - Dutycycle: 20%"`

and then proceed with

```
StringReplace[str1, {" " -> "_", "%" -> "", "." -> "", ":" -> ""}]
```

> `"M_vs_nsync_-_Dutycycle_20"`

Comment: looks good, but see my edited question: I seem to actually get another string than I pasted here before: `"M vs. \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(n\), \(sync\)]\) - Dutycycle: 20%"`. I'm a little lost in InputForm, FullForm, ...

Comment: And that's another reason why you'll hear here a mantra "don't use subscripts" - when you want to work with them further, they mess things up.

Comment: Well at least now, i start hearing it. Ok, I'll get rid of the subscripts. Would you mind adding `, ":" -> "", "." -> ""` to your `StringReplace`?

Comment: Now the answer is complete and works with the messy strings as well.