# How to tell whether a character is a letter-like form

Tags: string-manipulation, expression-test

Is there any way to programmatically tell whether a given character is a letter or letter-like form (see [this reference page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html) for what I mean)?

One idea I had was to use [`` FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13371/36508), to test whether the syntax parser would split the string (i.e. test whether `char <> "a"` is split), which seems to work. But I am looking for a more provably correct and less undocumented solution if at all possible.

Another idea was to simply check the reference page for a given character/preprocess the full list given above to build a "database" by hand, but it feels like there could be a more straightforward way, hence this question.

Comment: Yes, there is `LetterQ`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: That doesn't work on some characters though: `LetterQ@"\[Bullet]"` returns `False`...

Comment: Does `SyntaxQ` plus a check for numerics not work?

Comment: @b3m2a1 No, `SyntaxQ@"?"` is `True` unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm. Searching for every command involving `Letter` with `` *`*Letter* ``, I found `` System`Convert`MLStringDataDump`LetterLikeQ ``. If `s` is a `String`, it applies `` System`Convert`MLStringDataDump`LetterLikeAuxQ `` to `Characters[s]` and wraps it with `And@@`, so it seems to check if a string is entirely composed of letter like characters. Actually, the whole context `` System`Convert`MLStringDataDump `` seems to be interesting for you.

Comment: Thanks! I should really get into the habit of searching functions like this...
I just hope this covers all cases, as the list appears to be mostly hard-coded (or rather the complement is) - but since operators aren't changed to frequently, I don't think I need to worry too much.
Anyway, this will definitely be the solution I'll use :)

Comment: You're welcome. I hope it works out!

Answer (score 1):

Reading the documentation of [`Symbol`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Symbol.html), the following should work:

```
LetterLikeQ[char_] := Module[
  {ret},
  Begin["`llq`"];
  ret = Quiet@Check[Remove@Evaluate@Symbol@char; True, False];
  End[];
  ret
]
```

Some examples:

```
LetterLikeQ["a"]
(* True *)

LetterLikeQ["•"]
(* True *)

LetterLikeQ["\[Rule]"]
(* False *)
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Should be less hacky with ``Internal`SymbolNameQ``.

Comment: Good point - then this solution would also be a one-liner (``LetterLikeQ=Internal`SymbolNameQ``)...
But in that case I'd still prefer your solution, since both are undocumented, and yours is clearer in its intention