# Adapting "Find and Replace" functionality to work with Patterns

Tags: programming, front-end, notebooks, pattern-matching, customization

I was thinking if there is something like Find and Replace (<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) functionality adapted to work with patterns.

Probably not, but it seems possible to create this with some effort and skills in `low-level-notebook-programming`.

**My question is:** if there is not such functionality bulid in, maybe someone have worked on this?

Example of what I'm thinking it should be able to do:

```
Text["test string"]
```

[image]

```
Style["test string", Bold]
```

Comment: NotebookRead@Cells[] and work with CellExpression is the final choice I like.

Comment: I suppose it would be nice if we can use regexes in the find/replace box...

Comment: It doesn't exactly answer your question, but you probably should know that such functionality is available in the Wolfram Workbench, but restricted to the package files if I remember correctly. It will also search a whole directory, if you want. As that is basically a Mathematica plugin for eclipse, you'll also have access to a search with regexes.

Comment: @Jacob I appreciate the attention you are bringing to this question.  I have no answer however.  Hopefully much like "multi undo" we will some day see this included in *Mathematica* itself.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard that would be quite nice indeed. I remember I had a few ideas for improving my own function. One thing is that because we can only search on one line, we can always use a rule like this: `"\n*"~~patt~~"*\n" :>  patt`. A user then always only has to specify a pattern and does not have to keep `StringCases` in mind when entering input. Anyway thank you for commenting, such a comment provides a lot of motivation for me :).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I can send you package setup I;'ve done and basic dialog.nb release. I will not be able to finish it soon/ever. Do you want to proceed with this, or you are not interested in GUI creation? :)

Comment: @Kuba hey, well GUI creation is not my strongest/favorite point, but I think it would be nice to integrate our efforts :).

Comment: @Kuba I cannot really afford to get distracted right now though. Maybe this evening. I hope I wont forget it! (temporary message)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom my internet connection is broken at home so I was not able to share it :/

Answer (score 6):

I figured out a way to "get the string". It turned out that information was available on this site. This now works

```
pattSearch[nb_, patt_] :=
 pattSearch[nb, x : patt :> x]
pattSearch[nb_, rule : ((Rule | RuleDelayed)[__])] :=
 Block[
  {pNb, str, searchStr},
  pNb = NotebookGet[nb];
  str = First[
    FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`ExportPacket[pNb, "PlainText"]]];
  searchStr =
   First@StringCases[str, rule];
  NotebookFind[nb, searchStr];
  SetSelectedNotebook[nb]
  ]
```

Example of use

```
{1, 1};
nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
SelectionMove[nb, Before, Notebook];
pattSearch[nb, Shortest["{1," ~~ ___ ~~ "}"]]
```

In the example the expression `{1,1}` is selected.

Another example, with rules

```
(*This comment makes sure the line below is not at the start of the \
notebook*)
{1, {1, 1, 1}, 1, 1};
SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], Before, CellContents];
pattSearch[nb, 
 "\n" ~~ Shortest[___] ~~ 
   x : Longest["{1," ~~ Except["\n"] ... ~~ "}"] ~~ Shortest[___] ~~ 
   "\n" :> x]
```

**Notes**

Remember to use `Shortest`, or to handle newlines yourself. We cannot search over multiple lines. I have set it up in terms of rules, so that you can manually search on a line, like in the second example. The second example is ugly in that the pattern does not account for the possibility that the expression is at the start of the notebook.

It would be really nice if we could cycle through the expressions found by `StringCases`. Also using `First` when we may find no pattern is not nice. Maybe I will try make this nicer.

Comment: @Kuba I was hoping [my recent answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28967/4330) would help with this, but on closer look there is still a big gap to fill. Oh well :)

Comment: @Kuba oh there is no new version :). Just this remark, I felt things were related. Hope to catch you later.

Comment: And what now, you can't give this bounty yourself :) And I would like to add something to your answer rather than make new since I don't have time to polish this now. p.s. get you mail **** together Jacob! :)

Comment: @Kuba ahhh, sorry about missing your mail Kuba. My gmail is a total mess right now, ever since I subscribed to some overly active github repository :P. (temporary message)

Comment: Also I don't want the bounty myself, I want to get a rep of 6667 :). Feel free to edit my answer! It is fine if my rep vanishes.

Answer (score 6):

1. Parse cell objects to box data.
2. Use `MakeExpression[boxes]` to convert boxes to **Unevaluated** standard form expressions.
3. Find expressions that match the pattern `p_`.
4. Use `ToString[expr, InputForm]]` to convert the target expressions to strings in **InputForm**.
5. Find those strings in notebook and replace them to what you want (`r_`).

   ```
    NBReplace[p_, r_] := 
      Cases[NotebookRead /@ Cells[], Cell[BoxData[content_], "Input", ___] :> 
        (Cases[MakeExpression[#, StandardForm], 
           target: p :> 
              (NotebookFind[SelectedNotebook[], 
               ToString[target, InputForm]]; 
               NotebookWrite[SelectedNotebook[], ToString[r, InputForm]]; 
             target-> r), Infinity] &) /@ 
        If[ListQ[content], content, {content}]] // Flatten
   ```

*Examples:*

```
Style["test string", Bold]
NBReplace[Text[x_String], Style[x, Bold]]
```

results: `Style["test string", Bold]`

Also you can do:

```
Foo[1]
NBReplace[Foo[x_Integer], Bar[x + 5]]
```

results: `Bar[6]`

If you want to bind to a custom shortcut, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405/customizing-mathematica-shortcuts
Hope it makes sense, cheers :)

Comment: Thank You for those remarks. This link is also correct anticipation of my needs. :)