# Is there a programmatic equivalent of Edit > Find…?

Tags: front-end, replacement

Most things that can be done via the front-end interface in Mathematica can also be accomplished by some function. Is that the case for find-and-replacing? That is, is there some code I could execute in a Mathematica notebook that would have the same effect as me using the **Edit > Find…** window to replace all occurrences of `"find this text"` with `"replace with this text"` through the whole notebook?

Comment: Related: [(27001)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27001/121)

Answer (score 14):

*Update: I think I've got it.*

I found a token that does the replacement without bringing up a dialog.  The values from the last use of the **Find and Replace** dialog will be used.  The command is:

```
FrontEndExecute @ FrontEndToken[nb, "ReplaceAll"]
```

where `nb` is the target Notebook object.

To preset the Find and Replace fields one can modify the [`FindSettings`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSettings.html) option of the Front End like so:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {FindSettings, "FindString"}]  = "This";
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {FindSettings, "ReplaceBoxes"}] = "That";
```

Now:

[image]

```
FrontEndExecute @ FrontEndToken[nb, "ReplaceAll"]
```

After:

[image]

### Version 7

In version 7 under Windows I need this variation for the method to work:

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {FindSettings, "ReplaceString"}] = "That";
```

Comment: I can't make functions from `SystemResources/Find.nb` working, any idea? ``FE`Evaluate[
 FEPrivate`FindExpression[
  FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
   FrontEnd`$FrontEnd, {FindSettings, "FindBoxes"}], "Previous", 
  False, False, False]]``

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The `"FindString"` option seems to work as expected for me, but the `"ReplaceBoxes"` (or `"ReplaceString"`, which I also tried) option has no effect. (Mma 9.0.1.0)

Comment: @thecommexokid Possibly just the `CurrentValue` method is failing.  Please use the **Find and Replace** dialog with unique values for the find and replace fields, then evaluate `Options[$FrontEnd, FindSettings]` and tell me if the suboptions `"FindString"` and `"ReplaceBoxes"` exist, and have been set to the values you entered.  If so it should be possible to get this working.

Comment: Yes, `Options[$FrontEnd, FindSettings]` gives the values I entered.

Comment: And `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {FindSettings, "ReplaceBoxes"}] = "differentString"` returns `Null`, but if I execute `Options[$FrontEnd, FindSettings]` again afterward, the `ReplaceBoxes` setting shows the new value.

Comment: @thecommexokid Please try `"ReplaceString"` instead and see if it works.

Comment: I've been trying all possible combinations of `String` and `Boxes` all along.

Comment: @thecommexokid What operating system are you using?  With the right choice of `"ReplaceBoxes"` or `"ReplaceString"` this works in both 10.1 and 7.0 under Windows.

Comment: OS X Yosemite (10.10.3) with, as I mentioned above, *Mathematica* 9.0.