# Find and Replace in Notebook using a Pattern

Tags: notebooks, replacement

I would love to be able to use the power of Mathematica's patterns to find and replace within my code. I have searched for this on google, and so far I've come up with this:
http://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/patterns/findreplace.html

Which seems to suggest that I would need another program, Mathematica Workbench, to do so? Can anyone explain what this is to me? I guess this would involve paying some money to Wolfram

I also had a go with the code written in [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27001/adapting-find-and-replace-functionality-to-work-with-patterns). It seems to work part of the time, but has some undesirable features (or at least, undesirable to me!).
I want to replace all instances of `k[i_]` with `Subscript[k,i]` in my code (and I'm sure I would use this for more complex things later on too if I can get it to work now). Here are the current problems that I have, when I run `NBReplace[k[i_ ], Subscript[k,i]]`

*) Not all cases of `k[_]` are covered in my code. I can't see why this would be. I don't understand the code for the function in detail, but it looks to me like it should cover all cases

*) The code currently replaces `k[_]` with `k\_Subscript\_i`. I guess maybe I need to change an 'InputForm' somewhere to something else? Or I need to get rid of the code that's changing things to be strings?

*) The code replaces the `k[_]` in the function call itself, how can I make an exception for this cell?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: So the question is essentially the same as mine but you are not happy with answers there?

Comment: Well, yes I'd say that sounds about right. I think I've explained quite clearly why I'm not happy and what else I'd like it to do though. I actually only tried the code in the first and not the second response, but it looks to me like the code in the first response only searches a pattern and doesn't replace it, which isn't what I'm after

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adapting "Find and Replace" functionality to work with Patterns](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27001/adapting-find-and-replace-functionality-to-work-with-patterns)

Comment: I think your question is not very clear, actually. For example: "Not all cases of $k[\_]$ are covered in my code." What does this actually mean? Which cases are missed? Without those examples there is not much that can be said. Your second point is covered by changing the `InputForm` inside the `NotebookWrite` call to `StandardForm`. Also, please use code blocks for your code, not $\LaTeX$ markup.

Comment: And you can avoid changing the function call most easily by doing this from a separate notebook. Just add a third argument to `NBReplace` that specifies the notebook, rather than using `SelectedNotebook[]` to operate on the current one.

Comment: Well, thank you for answering two of the bullet points in my question, I see that these were clear enough to be understood and answered. I appreciate your help.
The other bullet point is what it says it is; not all cases of $k[_]$ are changed by the function. Here is a before and after example:

Comment: Before:
    `momcononshell4d = {k[1]\[CircleDot]k[2] -> s, 
   k[3]\[CircleDot]k[4] -> s, k[1]\[CircleDot]k[3] -> t, 
   k[2]\[CircleDot]k[4] -> t, k[1]\[CircleDot]k[4] -> u, 
   k[2]\[CircleDot]k[3] -> u};`

Comment: After:
    `momcononshell4d = {k[1]\[CircleDot]k[2] -> s, 
   k[3]\[CircleDot]Subscript[k, i] -> s, 
   Subscript[k, i]\[CircleDot]Subscript[k, i] -> t, 
   Subscript[k, i]\[CircleDot]Subscript[k, i] -> t, 
   Subscript[k, i]\[CircleDot]Subscript[k, i] -> u, 
   Subscript[k, i]\[CircleDot]Subscript[k, i] -> u};`

Comment: So not all cases of `k[_]` here have been covered by the code. If this is still unclear please explain why and I will try to further elucidate what I mean

Comment: Works for me, so not sure why it doesn't work for you: result is `momcononshell4d={Subscript[k, 1]\[CircleDot]Subscript[k, 2]->s,Subscript[k, 3]\[CircleDot]Subscript[k, 4]->s,Subscript[k, 1]\[CircleDot]Subscript[k, 3]->t,Subscript[k, 2]\[CircleDot]Subscript[k, 4]->t,Subscript[k, 1]\[CircleDot]Subscript[k, 4]->u,Subscript[k, 2]\[CircleDot]Subscript[k, 3]->u};` You would be better off to add this example to the question and to change all equation markup to code blocks at the same time.

Comment: OK, then now I have two problems. When I open a new file and run the code on its own in the file with the example I gave here, it does cover all cases but doesn't replace the `i` with the correct number. I'm very surprised this works for me and not for you. I have tried just `Cases[HoldComplete[k[1]], 
 target : k[i_] :> (target -> Subscript[k, i]), Infinity]!` to try to abstract out the part of the code that isn't working, and it gives `{k[1] -> Subscript[k, i]}` as the output, not replacing `i`. Do you know why this is?

Comment: When I run the code in the file I actually want to use it in, then it doesn't cover all cases. I think maybe this is because the code just searches for any given case with the `NotebookFind` function, instead of the specific case which is being considered at the point that the code encounters it? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Seems your *Mathematica* session is seriously screwed up, then. Your test case above gives `{k[1] -> Subscript[k, 1]}` for me, as it certainly should. Maybe you have some invisible characters or other structures in your notebook.

Comment: OK I restarted Mathematica and it sorted out that problem, thanks. I've also found the source of my problem with not all cases being covered. Here is the offending code: `Table[\n
 k[i], {i,5}]`, where the \n is a newline in my notebook, which is necessary for the problem to arise. NBReplace doesn't replace inside this statement, and the error I get is `Syntax::sntxf: "Table[ " cannot be followed by "k[i], {i, 5}]"`, even though what I've written is valid Mathematica code. Do you know why it doesn't like this?