# Is there a way to search for a WolframLanguage pattern in Notebook?

Tags: pattern-matching, notebooks, searching

Mathematica Notebook has a Search&Replace dialog, which allows to look for particular expressions. But I'd like to be able to find instances of code corresponding to a particular pattern. E.g. if the pattern is `x^_`, I'd like to find all occurrences of things like `x^2`, `x^(some*expression[352.34])` etc..

It seems that Search&Replace dialog doesn't have this option. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Wolfram Workbench can do this in a plain text package file (and also in notebooks but I don't know if it searches the notebook contents or the raw notebook expression).  I always assumed that this is not easy because expressions typed in a notebook (or text editor) may not be complete or error-free.  Are you looking to search only syntactically correct ones?  That may be much easier to implement (even if the functionality is not there yet).

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, I mainly need to do this with Mathematica output. I'm not quite in syntactically wrong code results.

Comment: Sorry, don't have time to compare it closely but it looks like at least closely related one: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27001/5478