# Function just gets mapped without any evaluation

Tags: function-construction

**Variable definitions are as follows:**

```
eBEG=0.;
epBEG=0.;
aNEXT = 0;
eNEXT=0.;
actStrain=0.;
epTRIAL=0.;
sigTRIAL=Range[0];
sigEND=Range[0];
```

**Constant definitions are as follows:**

```
delta=1.; 
inc=0.; 
delta=160.; 
sigu=300.; 
sigy=165.; 
c=sigu-sigy; 
aBEG=0.000001; 
smodulus=70000.; 
edot=0.01; 
maxiter=10.; 
k=0.;
tol=10.^-5; 
Dg=0.; 
dg=0.;
```

**Main code body:**

```
ge[inp_]= sigy + (c *(1- E^(-delta*inp) ));

func[inp1_] :=
(
  eNEXT=inp1; 
  sigTRIAL=smodulus*(eNEXT-epTRIAL); 
  aNEXT=aBEG; 
  f=Norm[sigTRIAL]-(sigy+(c*(1-E^(-delta*aBEG)))); 
  If[f<=0,
    sigEND=sigTRIAL,
    R=f-(dg*smodulus)-ge[aBEG+dg]+ge[aBEG];
    While[Abs[R] > tol && k < maxiter,
      dRG=-E - (c*delta*E^(-delta*(aBEG+dg)));
      Dg=-(dRG^-1)*R;
      dg=dg+Dg;
      R=f - (dg*E) - ge[aBEG+dg] + ge[aBEG];
      k=k + 1;
      dgg=dg];
    sigEND=(1-((dgg*smodulus)/Norm[sigTRIAL]))*sigTRIAL;
    epTRIAL=epTRIAL+(dgg*Sign[sigTRIAL]);
    aBEG=aBEG+dgg]; 
  eBEG=eNEXT; 
  aBEG=aNEXT; 
  sigEND
)
```

After evaluating I get no errors but when I apply function `func` to a list `strain`:

```
strain = Range[0, 0.1, 0.0001];
func /@ strain
```

the function just gets mapped without any evaluation.

```
{func[0.], func[0.0001], func[0.0002], func[0.0003], func[0.0004],(*and so on till last element of strain*)
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. The code does not produce the errors you report. Please provide a minimal example that stably reproduce the behaviour. Also please include variable and function definitions (e.g. for `ge`, `itr`, `edot`). Evaluate your code with a freshly started kernel. As it is at the momet, it likely will be closed as being too localized and requiring more input from you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: [This meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) has some tips on copying *Mathematica* into the site in a more readable form.  The lack of indentation makes your code hard to read quickly.

Comment: It may be possible that you have a hidden (non-printing) character in your notebook that doesn't show up in your post (see [(982)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/982/how-to-find-pieces-of-code-responsible-for-syntax-errors) for instance).

Comment: unrelated to the error, but `Abs[R]>tol` does nothing. perhaps you want `&&`  instead of the semicolon there.

Comment: the space between `If` and its `[` may be the issue

Comment: @george2079 I tried both the suggestions but none of them made any difference, of course the while condition works now. It didn't help in solving the actual problem.

Comment: Please put the definition of all variables involved in your code. We cannot help you without them; we can't replicate your issue.

Comment: What about changing from Append to AppendTo?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Yes it works now, I am getting the output correctly for `enet11` but for `stress11` I am getting a constant value of 70. I would like to verify whether your are getting the same results. Please note I have added dt to constant definition. Add it before you test the code.

Comment: Sorry, on mobile, that was just an obvious error that wasn't caught by others

Comment: `f` consistently evaluates to -25.0001 and the `f<=0` condition evaluates to `True`. as a result, `sigEND` is never updated. Many other similar things, such as `eNEXT` always being set to the same value.

Comment: I have evaluated your code as revised. I can not reproduce your problem. `strain = Range[0, 0.1, 0.0001]; func /@ strain` returns `{0., 7., 14., 21., 28., ..., 3.25706*10^10, 3.26041*10^10, 3.26376*10^10, 3.2671*10^10, 
 3.27045*10^10}`

Comment: I see no reason to re-open this question because the new problem the OP has is not reproducible. Suggest the OP revaluate code in a new session with a clean kernel.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a full answer, but the problems I mention below must be corrected before your code can be executed. This is not to say that the code will work even when these problems are solved. Correcting them is a necessary condition, not a sufficient one.

- The function `ge` is not defined.
- Your `While` has invalid semantics. Perhaps you meant to write

  ```
  While[Abs[R] > tol && k < maxiter, 
    dRG = -E - (c*delta*E^(-delta*(aBEG + dg)));
    Dg = -(dRG^-1)*R;
    dg = dg + Dg;
    R = f - (dg*E) - ge[aBEG + dg] + ge[aBEG];
    k = k + 1];
  ```
- The variable `inc` is undefined and can not be incremented with `inc++`. Even if it were defined, it would have no effect on the control of flow because it is never tested.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you can point out exactly how **function ge** is undefined. I thought a simple function definition required a formal parameter, in this case **inp** and a function body, in this case **sigy + ( c * ( 1-E^(-delta*inp) ))**.  So compound expression doesn't works for multiple test condition for while conditional? But it works for multiple If conditions.

Comment: @S_Arnav. There is no syntactically correct function definition in your code. Perhaps `ge[inp_] := sigy + (c*(1 - E^(-delta*inp)))` is what you should have written. To learn how to define functions, follow [this link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html)